# What is the best location for solution file in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, standards

I prefer for the solution file to be in the same folder as the project files in Visual Studio. I know this is accomplished by unchecking the "Create directory for solution" checkbox. However, VS 2008 defaults to having the box checked.

I am interested in other people's opinions on whether the solution file should live in the same directory.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

When a solution contain more than one project, I like a solution file in a parent directory and the project files in its child directories.

When a solution contains many projects (my current solution has 36 projects/assemblies), then I'll have:

- Grandparent: solution
- Child directories: "[solution folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haytww03(VS.80).aspx)" which are logical collections of projects
- Grandchildren: the projects themselves

---

I also agree with having the solution and its project in the same folder, *if* the solution only has one project. And if you start like this and want to add another project to the solution later, it's easy to change (e.g. create a new solution in a parent directory or move your existing solution, and add/re-add the existing project to it).

Just don't put several projects in the same folder.

Comment: Yes, in the root folder you have only the solution file and a folder for each project.

Comment: What's after the Grandparent Solution because you said the Grandparent is the solution?

Comment: @MJDelosSantos For example, the top (grandparent) might be a single `WebBrowser.sln`. Its subdirectories might be high-level folders for major components: `Dom`, `Css`, `RenderTree`, `Nerwork`, `Display`, `Chrome`. And each of these folders would contain sub-folders (grand-children), one for each project -- so the `Css` component might contain several CSS-related projects. At some point you might  further subdivide this into several solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer it something like this:

```
MyProject
  src
    Domain
    Application
    Infrastructure
    UI
  solutions
    MyProject
    Infrastructure
    Domain
```

Solutions folder contains solution folders. All projects are referenced from src folder.

Comment: I'm curious, what is the advantage of your approach?

Comment: Reusability                                             .